# Most efficient php boolean

Tags: php, boolean, performance

I'm quite new to php so I'm wondering what the most efficient way is to do this. For exmaple I have 3 different colors for 3 cars as variables. So car 1 gets color 1, car 2 color 2 and car 3 color 3. A car only gets a color if it has none already. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Something like this?

```
    if (is_car('1') AND !hascolor) {
        give_color_1 }
    else {
        echo 'Car already has a color'
    }
```

And then this boolean also for 2 and 3? Or is there a way to make this shorter? Thanks!

Comment: Look at this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp, will help you get started

Comment: I don't understand, why are you checking is_car? Create a class car with color variable. Leave it undef in constructor. Then create a method set_color, that will check for undef.

Comment: You are new to php, so do not bother with efficiency or length of your code. Write it to do it's job, continue learning, go back to it after some time and see for yourself if you have an idea to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using arrays. So for your example:

```
// initialize the array
$car_color_array = Array('1' => '', '2' => '', '3' => '');
$color_array = Array('1' => 'color1', '2' => 'color2', '3' => 'color3');

foreach ($car_color_array  as $car => $color){
    // if color is not set
    if ($color == ''){
        $car_color_array[$car] = $color_array[$car];
    }
}

// this should give cars with colors now
foreach ($car_color_array  as $car => $color){
    echo "<BR>Car: " . $car . " -> Color: " . $color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a `switch` statement:

```
if(!$hascolor) {
    switch(true) {
        case (is_car('1')): set_color($color_1); break;
        case (is_car('2')): set_color($color_2); break;
        case (is_car('3')): set_color($color_3); break;
        default: set_color($color_default); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This *could* be a good situation for a class and to practice OOP techniques if you aren't already familiar. This may not be ideal for your situation and there are probably easier ways, but I figured I'd show this way anyhow for the sake of knowledge!

Basically, define a class that requires a `$carNumber` when you create it (with an optional `$color` variable to pass). Then, create a method to alter that color. If there is already a color, you don't alter it, otherwise, you do.

```
class Car{
  public $hasColor = 0;
  public $carNumber = 0;
  public $color = null;

  public function __construct($carNumber, $color = null){
     $this->carNumber = $carNumber;
     if(is_null($color)){

     }else{
        $this->color = $color;
     }
  }

  public function alterColor($colorType){
    if($this->hasColor === 1){
    }else{
      $this->color = $colorType;
      $this->hasColor = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Now to implement the class...

`include_once("Car.php");`

```
$car1 = new Car(1);
$car2 = new Car(2);
$car3 = new Car(3, "Green");

$car1->alterColor("Red");
$car2->alterColor("Blue");
$car3->alterColor("Brown");
```

So `$car3`'s color shouldn't be altered, because it already was Green!

If you wanted to do a quick iteration, just do something like...

```
$cars = array($car1, $car2, $car3);
foreach($cars as $car){
   $car->alterColor("Blue");
}
```

This would change each car's color to "Blue". If you want to make each car a different color, you could probably do something like (trying to verify that `alterColor` will be called now, but I imagine it would)...

```
$cars = array($car1, $car2, $car3);
$colors = array("Blue", "Red", "Green");
for($i=0; $i<count($cars); $i++){
   $cars[$i]->alterColor($colors[$i]);
}
```

Hopefully that implants some ideas in your head! :-)

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code and it could contain errors.*